# GRUB menu not showing up on boot after replacing battery

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows, battery

I have an Asus F555L model with dual boot (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10).

On starting my computer, I always get the option to choose between OS from the GRUB loader. However, my battery was swelling, and hence I removed it and replaced it with a new one.

Since I have done this, my computer directly goes into Windows. I do not get the option of choosing from the GRUB loader at all.

Disabling Fast Boot from BIOS hasnt helped. I have also tried pressing, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd> on start but none of them helped.

I also tried putting the old battery back and it doesnt show up on that either.

What other options do I have to get my Ubuntu OS back with all my files and programs?

---

Boot screen from BIOS:
[image]

---

Output of efibootmgr -v

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,75833fa7-0273-4038-ac92-599cc968ad03,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...I................
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,75833fa7-0273-4038-ac92-599cc968ad03,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 1.27   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x17b611,0x800,0x1dd1000)..BO
```

Comment: I guess your BIOS was resetted to it's default configuration. What options do you have in the `Boot` menu?

Comment: Boot Option 1 (Windows), Boot Option 2 (Windows).

Comment: When restarting your PC, go to the BIOS menu and check the Boot order. If you still have Ubuntu, make it the first. Once it boots to Ubuntu, you can reinstall grub by running `sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64` for example

Comment: I do not see Ubuntu at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a switch `Legacy` to `UEFI`?

Comment: I do not see that option either. I added a picture of my boot screen.

Comment: It may not be in the `Boot` menu directly, it could be in the Startup or in some ofthe submenus (if your mobo is UEFI)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get there may be? From Windows or otherwise?

Comment: Can you boot the Ubuntu installer from USB, choose `Try Ubuntu...`, open a terminal and run `efibootmgr -v` and add the output via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1168707/edit) to your question please?

Comment: Added, please check.

Comment: Looks like you have to reinstall grub, please follow instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) .

Comment: You either need to manually add a new Ubuntu entry with efibootmgr or totally reinstall grub. And with Acer you may then have to reset "trust" on the ubuntu UEFI boot entry. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub using advanced options, not just menu update:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred This time it's not Acer but Asus

Comment: Hai mook765, this it it. It fixed it. If you could add that as an answer, I can mark it as accepted to help others in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `efibootmgr -v` revealed that the boot-entry for Ubuntu is broken, so I recommended to make use of [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which fixed the issue.